# How do combats work?

Tags: endless-legend

I'm not very familiar with [4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4X) gameplay in general, but some aspects of the battles remain quite unclear to me.  The following questions are about manual battles.  Quoting [the user's guide](http://www.multimondes.net/Amplitude/EndlessLegend/Manuals/User%27sManual.pdf):

**Battlefield and positioning**

> An important element [...] is that they take place directly on the Adventure Map, not on an abstract battlefield.  When you decide to attack an enemy army, you should choose the location of the battle carefully to take advantage of terrain opportunities: Altitude may grant you a bonus, and cliffs can prevent enemy units from reaching you.

How do you choose that location, exactly ?  Should I attack opponents from the side of their tile that will push me on the most valuable direction/area (for instance, west cliffs for my archers) ?  Is it possible to get a preview of what the battle area will be when engaging *before actually* engaging an enemy ?

Also, it can happen that more than 2 armies get engaged in a battle.  I think it's simply because when the effective battlefield spreads out, more than one army stands on it.  Once again: is it possible to get a preview of this area before engaging ?  Are those extra armies the "reinforcements" mentioned in the guide ?

> 4. Some units (greyed out) are placed in reserve and will enter the battle as reinforcements.

**Turns**

I was expecting a turn based combat system.  Turns out that it doesn't exactly work that way: once the resolution phase has started, each unit act for more than one turn and will eventually stop after 2 or 3 turns.  Is it normal ?  All the guide says about it is:

> Depending on the game settings, the battle can span several Order and Resolution phases.  Once these phases have completed, the battle ends.

Should I change something somewhere in order to have "normal" one-by-one turn gameplay ?

**Ranged attacks**

Where can I find the range of my ranged weapons ?  Is it possible to preview it during deployment or order phase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found some answers on [Amplitude forums](http://forums.amplitude-studios.com/).

**Battlefield and positioning**

Yes, you have to engage your opponent on the tile side where you want to locate your army.  If you hover your opponent while you keep right click pressed, a preview of the battlefield will appear.
Reinforcements are simply the other armies that are located in the battlefield.

**Turns**

In a nutshell, [it's not implemented yet](http://forums.amplitude-studios.com/showthread.php?27393-About-manual-combat&p=173468#post173468):

> In the final game we plan to offer a game setting that will allow you to control every round if you wish so. It will probably be 3 settings: simple (1 order phase), normal (3 phases), advanced (6 phases). In all these setting we always keep the same number of rounds (6 rounds), not to change the game balance.

**Ranged attacks**

Same as for turns: it's still a work in progress.

Comment: If you can, you should update this comment for the current state of the game. I'm curious about the same things the OP asked, and some of them seem to have changed from your answer. (=

Comment: Hey, yeah I supposed it has changed in the meantime, but I haven't played for a while.  Feel free to suggest any edit you'd like ;)